# Core Data: How to get a notification when document is saved?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I have noticed that when I call

```
[context save:nil];
```

the saving doesn't occur instantly. I tested that when I try to save and quit the app in one or two seconds. It only works if I keep the app open for 5+ seconds or so.

I have 2 questions:

- How can I know when the save is complete? A simple NSLog() will be enough, just for testing purposes.
- Can I force a save? Should I?

**Testing if [context save] is synchronous**

I have tested that many times and this is not the behavior that I'm getting. If I have this code:

```
[context save:nil]
NSLog(@"Saved");
```

I see the "Saved" log, quit the app, and when I launch it again and try to fetch the data - nothing there. **This doesn't happen if I wait about 5-10 seconds after I see the "Saved" message.**

Thoughts?

**Some code**

```
- (void)storeSales:(NSArray *)sales {
    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"EE LLLL d HH:mm:ss Z YYYY"];

    for (NSDictionary *saleDictionary in sales) {
        Sale *sale = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Sale" inManagedObjectContext:self.context];
        sale.productName = [saleDictionary objectForKey:@"description"];
        sale.date = [formatter dateFromString:[saleDictionary objectForKey:@"occured_at"]];

        NSLog(@"Stored new sale in database.");
    }

    [self.context save:nil];
}
```

**How I setup the UIManagedDocument**

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIManagedDocument *document;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSManagedObjectContext *context;

...

NSURL *url = [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject];
url = [url URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"SalesBot Database"];
self.document = [[UIManagedDocument alloc] initWithFileURL:url];

if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:[self.document.fileURL path]]) {
    [self.document saveToURL:self.document.fileURL forSaveOperation:UIDocumentSaveForCreating completionHandler:^(BOOL success) {}];
} else if (self.document.documentState == UIDocumentStateClosed) {
    [self.document openWithCompletionHandler:^(BOOL success) {}];
}

self.context = self.document.managedObjectContext;
```

**UPDATE 1**

I tried using NSNotificationCenter to receive NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification - but - I'm receiving it twice! Once right after [context save:nil] and again 5-10 seconds later!

Comment: Saving is synchronous process (usually _this_ is the problem). What `concurrencyType` has your context?

Comment: @iMartin How do I check that?

Comment: Show the code where you call save.  We could be missing something important, like calling it in an asynchronous code block.

Comment: @Jeremy posted some code and some more observation :)

Comment: @NikolayDyankov You may be using `-initWithConcurrencyType:`, but I assume you used simple `-init`. I don't know what is the default value, try logging `[context concurrencyType]`.

Comment: Wait, you are using `UIManagedDocument`? This may be important _detail_ for us.

Comment: @iMartin is there another way to use Core Data besides UIManagedDocument? :/ I will post more code.

Comment: @NikolayDyankov Yes, Core Data can be used (let's say) directly. You create model, coordinator and context by yourself, but this is another topic.

Comment: @iMartin If I use it that way, will I be able to save instantly, without the huge delay?

Comment: I posted second answer. I think you can accept it ;)

Comment: I didn't work with `UIManagedDocument` much, but I guess once you use correct save method, you don't need to care when they are really written to disk.

Comment: Naturally you've checked that whoever creates the persistent store coordinator hasn't gone with a SQLite store and `@"synchronous" : @"OFF"`? Someone would have had to go out of their way to do that but it would make the actual disk IO part asynchronous, though your OS should make that invisible anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So it seems like you are **using `UIManagedDocument`** above Core Data. This explains some things.

At first, use `-[UIDocument saveToURL:forSaveOperation:completionHandler:]` to save your document. From docs:

> You should typically use the standard `UIDocument` methods to save the document.
>   If you save the child context directly, you **only commit changes to the parent context** and not to the document store. If you save the parent context directly, you sidestep other important operations that the document performs.

`UIManagedDocument` works with ***two*** managed object contexts. One is working on main thread, the second is saving changes to file in background thread. This is **why your changes were saved, but after reopening were lost.** The second context did not finish save operation.

This explains also why your notification was triggered two times. One for each context.

Comment: @Jeremy No problem ;) It is nice thing once you know how to use it.

Comment: Turns out, it doesn't that way on a device. There is still delay. ... may I please say http://1.bp.blogspot.com/_ui8uMcTVrLk/Sy8rEx7M4gI/AAAAAAAAAbU/VRhnCrrH4lo/s400/fuuuu10.jpg

Comment: Are the changes **saved or not**? There may be the delay, but `UIDocument` **should force** the internal context to save when app is trasitioning to background. So again, did you lost the data or not?

Answer (score 2):

The save method is **not** an asynchronous process.  Anything that occurs after you call the save method will be executed after it has saved.

```
NSLog(@"About to force a save...");
[context save:nil];
NSLog(@"Now I know the save is complete!");
```

Comment: I have tested that many times and this is not the behavior that I'm getting. I see the NSLog() after the [context save], quit the app, and when I launch it and try to fetch the data - nothing there. This doesn't happen if I wait 5-10 seconds or so before I close the app. Thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

You can observe notification `NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification`.

Comment: This is generaly correct way, but it is not a good answer to this question.